# How can I access files in my USB pendrive (with YUMI & Ubuntu 12.04 installed in it)

Tags: 12.04

I am new to Ubuntu and would like to ask a question, any help would be greatly appreciated.

So, I installed YUMI multiboot USB creator into my pendrive, and added Ubuntu 12.04 as one of the Linux distributions, and I boot my computer using this pendrive.

SO I am running Ubuntu from this pendrive but when I m using Ubuntu how can I access the files in this pendrive? (because it also works as storage, i can access the files in it using explorer in Windows)

When I go to files in Ubuntu, I can find other devices like my other external harddisk, the harddisk in my computer...etc, but I just can't find my USB pendrive hence I can't access the files in it...

Please, can anyone tell me how to access my files in my pendrive? is this possible? Thank you very much~

Comment: When you connect your USB it should appear as an external disk on the **Unity Bar** (where the icons are). See [this image](http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_1QSDkzYY2vc/TcFo_Dkx4RI/AAAAAAAAES4/n6A70PBeJEc/firefox-unity1.png) to understand what I mean.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply ~~I am running Ubuntu from the USB pendrive so it has always been connected from the start

Comment: but the problem is that it doesn't show up as an external disk on the Unity Bar, I can see my computer's harddisk,but not the USB pendrive...

Comment: so I tried this:
~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x80d2f3ee

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *          63   604164095   302082016+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       604164096   606251007     1043456    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/sda3       606251722   625130185     9439232    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Comment: Disk /dev/sdb: 31.6 GB, 31625052160 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3844 cylinders, total 61767680 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *         128    61767679    30883776    c  W95 FAT32 (LBA)

                                                          This 31.6GB disk is my pendrive, but it doesn't show up as external disk in Unity Bar or in the file explorer

Comment: here is a screen shot, hope it helps...
http://i.minus.com/ijYlgufJeA39r.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The USB that you are booting Ubuntu from will not show up as an external disc.

I notice from your screen shot that it only has 1 partition.

It should be as simple as opening Nautilus then clicking Filesystem and navigating to the folder & files you want.

[image: File System]

Comment: OMG a did look into this but just found out that the files in the usb are in the cdrom folder of the file system! i look like an idiot now lol anyway thank you for the help~